# Calling a method in C++ from another .cc file

Tags: c++, methods

I am running CERN's root program and using C++ scripts for data analysis.

At the moment I have my own script running that does this analysis, but I need to use a method defined in someone else's file called 'ccd.cc':

```
bool CCDCuts12(obj1, int1)
    {...}
```

I need the boolean result of this method with obj1 and int1 created in my own code to use as follows:

```
if(CCDCuts12(obj1, int1))
    {...}
else {cout << "This Event Did Not Pass the Cuts" << endl;}
```

The problem is, ROOT gets very unhappy with me when I try this, so I am assuming that I am calling the method incorrectly and it needs some sort of [object].CCDCuts12(obj1, int1) in order to work... but I am not sure how to do it or what [object] would be...

For reference, I did already #include 'ccd.cc' at the top...

Comment: Is CCDCuts12 a freestanding function, or a method belonging to some class?

Comment: it should be a freestanding function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include the other C++ file. You should include the function definition in a header file (.h).

Comment: would that involve simply copying over the functions code into a ".h" file and including that? and once i do that, is my syntax for calling it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should include declaration of this function to this file

```
bool CCDCuts12(obj1, int1);
```

Probbly it should be include of `.h` file.

After that you should link both file into 1 program

```
your_compiler file1.cc file22.cc
```

Comment: can I just copy the function definition into a file with a .h extension of my choosing and then include it?

Comment: If you will not use `cc` file where it is now, yes. In other case, you will get redefinition error. Just use declaration.